# Adding UIbutton as subview fails to call the Selector when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

This is my code

```
                cell.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "dummyImage")
                cell.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                cell.button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
                cell.button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(8.0)
                cell.button.setTitle("PRESS HERE", forState: .Normal)
                cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.
                cell.imageView.addSubview(cell.button)
```

The button is getting displayed and is overlaying the image but the Selector

> pressed

is not getting called when I click the button. Help.

Comment: can you post image ? are you adding button as subview of uiimage ?

Comment: no need of this `cell.imageView.addSubview(cell.button)`, if you want to tap action for image

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik if I don't add cell.imageView.addSubview(cell.button) , button is getting hidden by the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not like

```
cell.imageView.addSubview(cell.button)
```

do like and try this

```
  cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
  cell.button.frame=CGRectMake(cell.imageView.frame.origin.x, cell.imageView.frame.origin.y, cell.imageView.frame.size.width, cell.imageView.frame.size.height)
 cell.button.tag = indexpath.row
  cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents. TouchUpInside)
cell.contentview.addSubview(cell.button)
```

then check like

```
 func pressed(sender:UIButton)
{
    NSLog("tapped index==%@",sender.tag)
}
```

Comment: thanks.  cell.contentview.addsubView(cell.button) did the job.

Answer (score 0):

`pressed:` implies that you have a selector in the method you are calling.

try with "pressed" or  change your function to something like:

```
func pressed(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println("Button tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

`UIImageView` has this property to `false` by default.